# Cassandra - No Rows Returned

Tags: select, indexing, cassandra, cql

Here is my Table:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    id uuid,
    day     text,
    mytime      timestamp, 
    value       text,
    status      int,

PRIMARY KEY ((id, day), mytime )
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (mytime desc)
;
```

Here is the Index:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_status ON mytable (status);
```

When I run this select statement, I get the expected results:

```
select * from mytable 
where id = 38403e1e-44b0-11e4-bd3d-005056a93afd 
AND day = '2014-10-29'
;
```

62 rows are returned as a result of this query.

If I add to this query to include the index column:

```
select * from mytable 
where id = 38403e1e-44b0-11e4-bd3d-005056a93afd 
AND day = '2014-10-29'
AND status = 5
;
```

zero rows are returned. (there are several records with status = 5)

If I query the table...looking ONLY for a specific index value:

```
select * from mytable 
where status = 5
;
```

zero rows are also returned.

I'm at a loss. I don't understand what exactly is taking place.

I am on a 3 node cluster, replication level 3. Cassandra 2.1.3

Could this be a configuration issue at all..in cassandra.yaml ?

Or...is there an issue with my select statement?

Appreciate the assistance, thanks.

UPDATE:

I am seeing this in the system.log file, ideas?  ...

```
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:1266] 2015-03-24 15:20:26,596 CassandraDaemon.java:167 - Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:1266,1,main]
java.lang.AssertionError: /cdata/cassandra/data/my_table-c5f756b5318532afb494483fa1828675/my_table.idx_status-ka-32-Data.db
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableReader.getApproximateKeyCount(SSTableReader.java:235) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.runMayThrow(CompactionTask.java:153) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionTask.executeInternal(CompactionTask.java:76) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionTask.execute(AbstractCompactionTask.java:59) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionManager$BackgroundCompactionTask.run(CompactionManager.java:240) ~[apache-cassandra-2.1.3.jar:2.1.3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
```

Comment: Presumably what you think is "5" for `status` is not really stored as `5` in the database.  Perhaps it is a string with space characters on one side or hte other.

Comment: Are you trying it using cqlsh?

Comment: I have tried cqlsh, same results. However, i do get the expected results when I run these queries in PROD. In my dev environment, I do NOT get the expected results.  In DEV, i inserted a test records, then performed the select again. The record I entered WAS returned.  I'm wondering if the table needs to be repaired? or something similar?

Comment: What I don't understand is how you can have 62 records with the same primary key. My understanding is when you insert a new record with primary key, the old one gets marked as deleted (tombstone).  Try turning tracing on in cqlsh an see what it shows.

Comment: 62 rows are returned because of the column clustering on the "mytime" column. 62 occurrences for that ID/DAY primary key , all with different timestamps in column "mytime".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your steps above and was able to query rows by `status=5` just fine.  One thing I can suggest, is to try rebuilding your index.  Try this from a command prompt:

```
nodetool rebuild_index mykeyspace mytable idx_status
```

Otherwise, IMO the best way to solve this, is **not** with a secondary index.  If you know that you're going to have to support a query (especially with a large dataset) by `status`, then I would seriously consider building a specific, additional "query table" for it.

```
CREATE TABLE mytablebystatus (id uuid, day text, mytime timestamp, value text, status int, 
PRIMARY KEY ((status),day,mytime,id));
```

This would support queries only by `status`, or `status` and `day` sorted by `mytime`.  In summary, I would experiment with a few different PRIMARY KEY definitions, and see which better-suits your query patterns.  That way, you can avoid having to use ill-performing secondary indexes all together.

Comment: Agreed. I actually do have a secondary table for status queries. Which is what this process i'm going through is about. I've been using the indexes to get out certain rows from the main table...to populate the secondary table. Then turf the indexes.  I did rebuild indexes earlier today ...which did not initially work...however, i rebuilt them a second time...and they did appear to work again.  So...i think i'm back in business.  You're analysis of the situation was spot on. Thanks Bryce.